# How can I do this? $\int\frac{dx}{x^4+1}$

Tags: integration, exponentiation, indefinite-integrals, fractions

I tried to integrate this: $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{dx}{x^4+1}$

I tried to do it with the partial fractions method (after factoring the denominator), but the process is really large, and I got a lot of mistakes.

Is there another way to solve this?

Thanks in advance :)

P.S. I'd put what I did, but I don't have the papers anymore, sorry :(